# If the monoid algebra $R[M]$ is finitely generated, then $M$ is a finitely generated monoid.

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid, finitely-generated, algebras

> Consider a commutative, cancellative, torsion-free monoid $M$ and a commutative ring $R.$ If the monoid algebra $R[M]$ is finitely generated as an $R$-algebra, then $M$ is finitely generated.

I am following the proof of the above fact (Proposition 2.7 in Bruns and Gubeladze's *Polytopes, Rings, and K-Theory*), and the authors' exposition leaves something to be desired.

Explicitly, the argument is as follows.

> We will assume that $f_1, \dots, f_n$ generate $R[M]$ as an $R$-algebra. By definition of $R[M],$ there exist finitely many symbols $x^{m_i}$ and scalars $r_{m_i}$ such that $f_i = \sum r_{m_i} x^{m_i}.$ Consider the finite set $G$ that consists of the elements $m_i$ in $M.$ We have that $M' = \mathbb Z_+ G$ is a finitely generated monoid. We claim that $M = M'.$ Certainly, we have that $M \supseteq M',$ hence it suffices to prove the inclusion $\subseteq.$ Observe that any $R$-linear combination of the monomials $f_1^{a_1} \cdots f_n^{a_n}$ with $a_i \in \mathbb Z_+$ can be written as an $R$-linear combination of monomials $x^a$ for some element $a$ of $M'.$ Considering that $f_1, \dots, f_n$ generate $R[M]$ as an $R$-algebra, it follows that each of the symbols $x^b$ for $b$ in $M$ can be written as an $R$-linear combination of some $f_1^{a_1} \cdots f_n^{a_n}$ with $a_i \in \mathbb Z_+,$ and thus, each of the symbols $x^b$ is an element of $R[M'].$

From here, Bruns and Gubeladze conclude that "this implies that $M = M'$;" however, I fail to see why this should be true. I would appreciate any assistance or suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you fail to see why $M \subseteq M'$ from the arguments in the proof or just the intuition behind the result $M = M'$?

Comment: Both, I suppose. I am not convinced from the argument that $M = M',$ and I don't see why it should be the case that $M \subseteq M'.$ I have seen this form of argument before -- show that something is finitely generated by establishing that it is equal to some explicit finitely generated object -- but in this case, I don't see the inclusion $\subseteq.$

Comment: See my answer below, hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim.** Consider a commutative ring $R$ and a free $R$-module $X$ with a basis $B.$ Given any subset $B’$ of $B,$ we have that $X' \cap B = B',$ where $X'$ is the $R$-submodule of $X$ that is spanned by $B'.$

*Proof.* Certainly, we have that $B' \subseteq X' \cap B$ since every element of $B'$ is contained in $B$ and the elements $b' = 1_R \cdot b'$ of $B'$ are all contained in $X'.$ Conversely, given any element $x$ of $X' \cap B,$ we have that $x = r_1 \cdot b_1 + \cdots + r_n \cdot b_n$ for some elements $r_i$ of $R$ and $b_i$ of $B'$ and $x = b = 1_R \cdot b$ for some element of $B.$ Observe that $b = r_1 \cdot b_1 + \cdots + r_n \cdot b_n$ is a linear combination of elements of $B.$ But the expression of any element in $X$ as an $R$-linear combination is uniquely determined by the scalars $r_i$ and basis elements $b_i,$ hence we must have that $x = b = b_i$ for some index $i,$ i.e., $x$ is in $B'.$ We conclude therefore that $X' \cap B = B'.$ QED.

By definition, we have that $R[M]$ is the free $R$-module with a basis consisting of the monomials $x^m$ for each element $m$ of $M.$ We may view $M$ as a subset of $R[M]$ via the injective map $M \to R[M]$ that sends $m \mapsto x^m.$ We have shown that for each element $b$ of $M,$ we have that $x^b$ is in $R[M'],$ from which it follows by our identification that $M \subseteq R[M'].$ By the claim above, we have that $M = R[M'] \cap M = M'.$

Answer (score 1):

Let us expound on the last line as follows to strengthen our intuition of the result.

> Considering that $f_{1}, f_{2}, \cdots f_{n}$ generate $R[M]$ as an $R$-algebra, it follows that each of the symbols $X^{b}$ for $b \in M$ can be written as an $R$-linear combination of some $f_{1}^{a_{1}} \cdots f_{n}^{a_{n}}$ with $a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$...

This line recalls what it takes to be a *system of generators* for $R[M]$ as an $R$-algebra to collect sufficient arguments to prove the next point.

> and thus, each of the symbols $X^{b}$ is an element of $R[M′]$.

Here, the author has used that fact that any linear combination of $f_{i}^{a_{i}}$ can be written as a linear combination of monomials $X^{a}$ with $a \in M'$. Now, fix some $b \in M$. Since

- $X^{b}$ can be written as an $R$-linear combination of monomials $f_{1}^{a_{1}} \cdots f_{n}^{a_{n}}$ with $a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, and
- any $R$-linear combination of $f_{i}^{a_{i}}$ can be written as a linear combination of monomials $X^{a}$ with $a \in M'$

then, $X^{b}$ can be written as a linear combination of monomials $X^{a}$ with $a \in M'$.

From here, we can see that $X^{b} \in R[M']$. Hence, we have $b \in M'$ by definition of $R[M']$. At this point, we have shown that whenever we fix $b \in M$, we also have $b \in M'$.

Hence, we get the desired inclusion $M \subseteq M'$.

**P.S.** Sorry, took me a while to find this PDF link http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.2385&rep=rep1&type=pdf to check in context what the author might have assumed the reader must already know at the point of presentation. Noticed that the version that I found was an incomplete version of the monograph. :)

**Update:** Corrected commas as products in $f_{1}^{a_{1}} \cdots f_{n}^{a_{n}}$. Thanks, @Carlo! :)

Comment: I noticed that you have fundamentally altered one of the statements in the proof in the first quotation of your solution: there are not commas; we are looking at the monomials $f_1^{a_1} \cdots f_n^{a_n}.$

Comment: Regardless, once we show that $x^b$ is in $R[M']$ for every $b$ in $M,$ we seem to be done. Both you and the authors believe that this is due to the definition of $R[M'],$ but I am not yet convinced. By definition, $R[M']$ is the free $R$-module with a basis of $x^a$ for all $a$ in $M'.$ We have shown that $x^b$ is in $R[M'],$ but we have not shown that it is a basis element of $R[M'],$ so how can we conclude that $b$ is in $M'?$

Comment: We have shown that $x^{b} \in R[M']$ holds for all $b \in M'$. These $x^{b}$'s form the set of monomials in $R[M']$ which is trivially a basis of $R[M']$ as a free module. In fact, this coincides with what we call the *monomial basis* of $R[M']$ as a polynomial ring, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_basis#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20the%20monomial%20basis,the%20set%20of%20all%20monomials. By definition of a polynomial, every polynomial can be uniquely written as a linear combination of monomials. Hence, the $x^{b}$'s form a basis for $R[M']$. Does this help?

Comment: As for the comment about monomials $f_1^{a_1} \cdots f_n^{a_n}$, ah yes they are not commas but products. In fact, the version in the link to the PDF says *products* instead of monomials. Yes I'll need to edit that part of the answer. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: I am still uncertain. Unfortunately, your second-to-last comment seems to have some typos. We have shown that $x^b$ is in $R[M']$ for all $b$ in $M.$ But I cannot see why it is true that the set $\{x^b \,|\, b \in M\}$ is "trivially" a basis of $R[M']$ -- let alone why it is the monomial basis of $R[M'].$ In fact, I think that the monomial basis of $R[M']$ is $\{x^a \,|\, a \in M\}.$ Unless we know that $M = M'$ (which is what we are trying to prove), I see now reason for $\{x^b \,|\, b \in M\}$ to form a basis for $R[M'].$

Comment: Ahh yes, I see that I skipped a step in my second-to-last comment. Indeed, what directly follows from the result $x^b \in R[M']$ is that we have $x^b \in R[M']$ for all $b \in M$ (not for all $b \in M'$). It seems that we have to emphasize that fact that $M' \subseteq M$ to eliminate the perceived uncertainty on the result. Now that we have $M' \subseteq M$, then now we have $X^b \in R[M']$ for all $b \in M'$ and we can proceed accordingly. Now does this help eliminate the uncertainty now? :)

Comment: I understand that there are no "trivial" things when you want a really solid understanding behind a result, that you can cling to it without doubt. Rigor must still persist behind these "trivial" things (and often this is where claimed proofs of famous unsolved conjectures go wrong, the "trivial" claims). And that also tests understanding on my side (if I really understood it). To be honest, I got skeptical of the result for a while too when you challenged it and I needed to shed light on the rigor behind my intuition. :) Thanks for the further questions and +1 for your comment! :)

Comment: We know that for each element $b$ in $M,$ we have that $x^b$ is in $R[M'].$ Particularly, for any element $b_0$ in $M - M',$ we have that $x^{b_0}$ is in $R[M'].$ Why should this be a contradiction? I still fail to see your point. We already know that $x^a$ is in $R[M']$ for all $a$ in $M'$ by definition of $R[M'].$

Comment: Perhaps this comes down to a matter of semantics. By my understanding, the symbols $x^a$ such that $a$ is in $M'$ form a basis for $R[M'].$ Conversely, if the symbol $x^b$ is in $R[M'],$ does that imply that $x^b$ is a basis element of $R[M']$ so that $b$ is in $M'?$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I reached out to the authors, and they were able to assist me. I have provided an answer above.